# NFC internal reader calls another apps

Tags: java, android, nfc

Problem is in next. When I offer chip to the NFC reader(internal), system prompts me to select the application that I want to work with the chip, but without my application. I want work with chip with my internal reader, and for this I need to catch intent on "onNewIntent" to work with it.

I have a class extended from FragmentActivity, and in this class I have overrided method onNewIntent (Intent intent). in manifest file I have 
"uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC".

System does not recognize my app, as the app what can work with NFC. What I'm do wrong? And where problem can be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you registered an intent filter on your manifest?? Check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html